# Create OData services using Play Framework

Tags: playframework, odata

Does Play framework (using Java) supports to create OData services? 
There is no documentation about this in PlayFrameworks website. We are clueless about this. Can somebody helps us to understand whether it supports or not?
It is highly appreciated, if you can give some relevant links.

Comment: You just asked this two hours before this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514184/create-olingo-odata-services-by-using-play-framework

Comment: You can use Olingo to handle rendering the OData. You will still have to wire it to your model and define the routes and create a controller  to make the appropriate calls to the Olingo libraries when you receive a user request.  It won't plug in out of the box, you'll have to put some effort into it.